# Filtering multiple csv files by creation date and concatenate into one pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, filtering

I would like to read just csv last 7 days createds csv files from a directory into pandas and concatenate them into one big DataFrame. I have not been able to figure it out though. Here is what I have so far:

Edit: I'm trying to filter by the creation date of csv file, not by any column in csv.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
import glob

fileday = datetime.now() - timedelta(7)
fileday = datetime.strftime(fileday, '%Y%m%d')

path = r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")

li = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: is there a date column in the csv, or is it the date included in the filename? in any case please update your example to include it.

Comment: I'm trying to filter by the creation date of the CSV file, not a column in csv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using pandas, let's use a combination of pathlib and pandas.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd 

p = Path(r'C:\DRO\DCL_rawdata_files')

all_files = p.glob('*.csv')

df = pd.DataFrame({'files' : all_files})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['files'].apply(lambda x : x.stat().st_mtime),unit='s')
```

---

```
# filter your files.
trg_files = df[df['date'] >= pd.Timestamp('now') - pd.DateOffset(days=7)]['files'].tolist()


dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in trg_files]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for filename in all_files:
    df = df.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
```